# making the border of a vb.net form semi-transparent

Tags: vb.net, transparent

Is there any way to embed a vb.net form to another vb.net form. What I am trying to do is to make Form-A semi-transparent and Form-B as the embedded main form. So that the final application has a semi transparent border around it . Also I don't want to use a MDI form.

Edit: How to make the border of a vb.net form semi-transparent without using MDI form.

Comment: Without using MDI, I can think of no way to do this. Short of some major winforms hacking. I have an idea but will have to wait till tomorrow to have access to a computer with Visual Studios.

Comment: thank you, i will wait till tommorrow

Comment: Im gonna download now, so might be around late tonight.

Comment: May i ask what exactly you are doing? I'm a little curious.

Comment: just trying to make the border around the form semi-transparent just like you did but without the focus issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've simplified the code a bit and hooked up most of the events to a single method.  There is no longer a Form-A, just a Form-B.  Form-B now creates it's own Form-A on the fly without any need to actually make a code file.  I moved the border size to a variable so it would be easy to adjust it.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class InnerForm
    Private borderSize As Integer = 10
    Private border As Form = New Form()

    Private Sub InnerForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        border.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
        border.ShowInTaskbar = False
        border.BackColor = Color.Blue
        border.Opacity = 0.5
        border.Enabled = False

        RefreshBorder()
    End Sub

Private Sub DrawRectangle()
    Dim p As New Drawing2D.GraphicsPath()
    p.StartFigure()
    p.AddArc(New Rectangle(0, 0, 40, 40), 180, 90)
    p.AddLine(40, 0, border.Width - 40, 0)
    p.AddArc(New Rectangle(border.Width - 40, 0, 40, 40), -90, 90)
    p.AddLine(border.Width, 40, border.Width, border.Height - 40)
    p.AddArc(New Rectangle(border.Width - 40, border.Height - 40, 40, 40), 0, 90)
    p.AddLine(border.Width - 40, border.Height, 40, border.Height)
    p.AddArc(New Rectangle(0, border.Height - 40, 40, 40), 90, 90)
    p.CloseFigure()
    border.Region = New Region(p)
End Sub

Private Sub RefreshBorder()
    border.Show()
    border.Size = New Size(Me.Width + borderSize * 2, Me.Height + borderSize * 2)
    border.Location = New Point(Me.Location.X - borderSize, Me.Location.Y - borderSize)
    DrawRectangle()
    SetWindowPos(border.Handle, Me.Handle, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE Or SWP_NOACTIVATE)

    Me.BringToFront()
End Sub


    Private Sub frmMAin_Refresh(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
        Handles Me.GotFocus, Me.Move, Me.Activated, Me.SizeChanged, MyBase.Shown

        'dont show when maximized or minimized, else show it'
        If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized Or Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
            border.Hide()
        Else
            RefreshBorder()
        End If
    End Sub

    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function SetWindowPos(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As IntPtr, ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal uFlags As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function

    Public Const SWP_NOSIZE As Int32 = &H1
    Public Const SWP_NOMOVE As Int32 = &H2
    Public Const SWP_NOACTIVATE As Int32 = &H10
End Class
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: So how do I get the border color semi transparent ? Can u upload a working sample code somewhere ?

Comment: I tried your method, the only problem is that when I change the opacity of main form the child form also changes its opacity

Comment: Sorry... misunderstood the qeustion (not sure how but I did).  I messed around with the code posted by giodamelio and I think I got it to work.  Check my updated answer.

Comment: Ok, it solved the focus issue , but the new problem is that after I  minimize the form, the border disappears.

Comment: I've tweaked the code a bit, streamlined it a bit, and I think it should be working.  Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: problem with minimize  is solved but after you maximize the form, the  whole form becomes blue.

Comment: Updated. I added "Me.BringToFront()" to the RefreshBorder() method and that seems to fix it.

Comment: @Patricker Is it possible to make the corner of the border rounded ?

Comment: @Patricker Another Problem, I executed the code, the form displayed fine then I opened a folder (say my computer) and  then to bring the form in front I just clicked on the Form's icon in the task-bar, Viola the border is gone :(

Comment: @Patricker Is there anyway to fix this issue? Its a similar focus issue problem

Comment: @subanki I've just updated my code again. I'm using SetWindowPos to force the the zindex of the border to always be right behind the parent. Try that out.  I included the whole file so you could see the required Import statement at the top.

Comment: @Patricker I forgot to delete the previous code :P, the code works great , once again thanks.

Comment: @subanki - I added rounded corners.  See the addition of the DrawRectangle method, and the call to it in RefreshBorder().

Comment: @Patricker You said Form B makes Form A while run-time. Then how can I add a simple Label to Form A

Comment: @subanki - Two options: One, don't have from b auto generate form a and have it actually be a seperate form.  Two, create the control in code and add it by hand, something like Dim lbl as new Label() border.controls.add(lbl).  I figured you would want the border to be only a border, but if you want to put other controls in it I would probalby make a seperate form for it instead of letting it be auto generated.

Comment: @Patricker I tried the second method but the label is not showing up :(

Comment: @Patricker  This is what I tried.......line1: Dim lbl As New Label()
        line2: border.Controls.Add(lbl)
        lien3: lbl.Text = "Hello"
        line4: lbl.Location = New Point(1, 1)

Comment: @Patricker To try out the 1st method, what changes should I make in the codes

Comment: @subanki - Make a new windows form, we'll say it's called FromA, put your label in it.  Then change "Private border As Form = New Form()" to "Private border As FormA = New FormA()"

Comment: @Patricker, I am using the top of the border as a title bar where I need to put  a title text , minimize button and a close button, how do I do that. Since border.Enabled = False, I am unable to put put buttons. Any way around this problem.

Comment: @Patricker I split the border into two parts one for top (title) and one for bottom (rest of the form). Problem Solved :D

Answer (score 2):

You should check this out. It is in C# but you could try to get help translating it. [Extending Form with Non-Client Area Painting](http://geekswithblogs.net/kobush/articles/CustomBorderForms.aspx). It is way above my head and since you are new to, it might be pretty tricky.

First of, since you did not specify, I am assuming you are using winforms and not WPf or Asp.net, both of which I have next to no experience with.
I have a method that is just messing with a bunch of winforms property's. It is kinda glitchy on my winxp, box but it works :). Here is the code for the two forms, I have included th property's in code to simplify things.

The Main form

```
Public Class frmMAin
    Dim border As Form = New frmBackground()

    Private Sub frmMAin_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.GotFocus
        RefreshBorder()
    End Sub
    Private Sub frmMAin_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        RefreshBorder()
    End Sub

    Private Sub RefreshBorder()
        border.Show()


        border.Size = New Size(Me.Width + 20, Me.Height + 20)
        border.Location = New Point(Me.Location.X - 10, Me.Location.Y - 10)
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmMAin_LostFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.LostFocus
        border.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmMAin_Move(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Move
        RefreshBorder()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The Background Form

```
Public Class frmBackground

    Private Sub frmBackground_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
        Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
        Me.BackColor = Color.Blue
        Me.Opacity = 0.5
    End Sub
End Class
```

And it turns out something like this.
[image]

This code still has some issues with focus but is mostly functional. Also keep in mind this is not the most "elegant" way to solve this problem, there is most likely a better way to do this with some system dll. You also might try WPF, as I hear you have much more control over look then in winforms.

Comment: Nice, Thanks. I also came with something similar like this. I tried your code it works well. only problem is with the focus , when i click on the background form it comes on top of the main form ...any way to put it always in background of the main form with out using topmost = true ? Also if possible can u tell how to do this in WPF. I dont much abt this . I just started vb.net yesterday :P

Comment: That is the same problem I ran into and could not figure out. But its late and the programming part of my brain turned off about an hour ago :|. I'll give it another crack in the morning.

Comment: I added a link to the top of my answer.

Comment: Thank you for effort giodamelio. I visited the site and went through the link but couldn't understand much. @Others Someone please convert this to vb.net

Comment: @giodamelio will u be able to help me if the c# code is translated to vb.net ?

Comment: I might, I might not. That stuff is right around the edge of my knowable. I would defiantly like to learn though.

Comment: OK this site says it converts C# code to vb.net ...http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: I used that site, and the code is above my head. You are gonna need someone else's help on this one, sorry.